# refresh contact list mechanism

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

In my web application there is a list of contacts named as "Preferred Contacts". This list is refreshed after every 2 minutes. On this list, user can perform multiple actions like selecting a contact and do the call on right click, delete the contact from list etc.

Request is handled in the following manner:

```
Browser --> Ajax Request --> Java Servlet --> SOAPRequest --> SOAPResponse -->
Ajax Response --> Browser
```

Problem is how to synchronize the end user actions with Automatic refresh mechanism?

Lets take the below scenario:

When list is refreshing after 2 minutes and meanwhile user delets one contact then refreshed list contains the deleted contact as well because refresh request was sent earlier to deletion request.

Currently, I have handled this situation like While refreshing is in process, then user cannot perform any edit operation on the list. Other option can be like queue all the operations that user has performed while refreshing and

But I want to synchronize these actions in such a way that these things remain transparent to end user? Is there any way to do this in Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply ignore responses for requests that were made *before* the additional user action.

One way to do this would be to have a sequence number on requests, for instance, a `var requestNum = 0` that gets incremented with each request. The callback for each refresh request should know its own unique `requestNum`, and if its own `requestNum` is less than the current `requestNum`, then the callback will do nothing, because that would mean that a subsequent request has been made that will respond more accurately.

Another, more aggressive way to accomplish this would be to [abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29) active requests if the user performs any additional action that would affect the validity of those request responses, as in the case you described.